# create a new sqlite table within the same database that was created during initialmigration

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, model-view-controller

I am new to fairly new to programming and started a new project using asp.net core and MVC.
Since i wanted to see what was going on behind the scenes, i implemented authentication and authorisation manually using IdentityUser and IdentityDbContxt.
During the initial migration, a bunch of tables were created that allows the users to register and then login in. I have implemented all of that.
Now I want to create a new table within the same database that will let the users submit their names and address. I believe i can just create a new table using sqlite GUI  and work with that, but how do I create a UserProfileModel.cs file and have that schema show up on the database?
My apologies if my question is not very clear. Also , I am working with microsoft stack on a mac :).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can always extend the IdientityUser, add migration, update the database and names and addresses will be added to the table.

```
public class UserProfileModel:IdentityUser
```

If you want to have more models with tables, you have to make a class that extends the IdentityDbContext, pass the db options to the constructor and add your DbDets, wich will be use for creating the tables.

```
 public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<UserProfileModel> Residences { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext (DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
```

Then, where you configure the services you have to add the database,

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(configuration.GetConnectionString("Your Connection String")));
```

I assume you have already made that, maybe with IdentityDbContext, but you can add your custom DbContext.

Now you can inject your AppDbContext wherever you want to use it. Probably to a service or a repository.

Comment: Thanks, I think i made some progress using DbSet property . I can now see the UserProfileModel in the migration and model snapshot. But when i run the add migration and update command, my sqlite database does not show the new table. Wondering whats going on

Comment: so I kept getting this error since yesterday, "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'table "AspNetRoles" already exists'.
 
So i just got rid of the migration folder and re did the initial migration and now my new table is showing. I think i just need to dig a little deeper into EF and how it really works, similar to what i did with authentication and authrisation.